# Get Object keys in insertion order in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, google-chrome-devtools

I have a large JavaScript object which has keys beginning with an integer like:

```
const obj = { 
              '0//America' : ['New York', 'Dallas', 'SF'] , 
              '0//UK' : ['London'] ,
              '1//Australia' : ['Sydney', 'Melbourne'] 
            }
```

When I do `Object.keys(obj)`, I get keys in random order, something like :

```
["1//Australia", "0//America", "0//UK"]
```

How can I get the keys in right order?
Please note that above object is just a small representation of the actual object, and it might return the keys in correct order when you run it. But my object is very large and behaves differently.

UPDATE: Sorry guys, but I just figured that the objects are not inserted in the correct order. But somehow, `console.log(obj)` shows the objects in sorted order, causing confusion.
Is there a way to prevent this behaviour in Chrome Dev Tool's console?

Also, what will be the best way to sort these objects by their object keys, given that it's a large Object containing lots of objects?

Comment: Couldn't reproduce, tried in latest chrome in devtools and result was `["0//America", "0//UK", "1//Australia"]`

Comment: If you need elements in a order it is better to use array, it is meant for ordered things

Comment: Modern JS, order of string based keys is insertion order.  But on older Browsers this is not guaranteed.  And a quick test in Chrome the order is identical every time.  And like mentioned above, can't re-produce, and arrays are usually a better container for stuff you want sorting.

Comment: `it might return the keys in correct order when you run it` - AFAIK, Object.keys would just loop  through the properties and returns an array and usually it follows the order of insertion.

Comment: you can add a unique key to your object. that way you will have control on how to filter,orderby or do other things with your object. example of unique key can be date, id number the list goes on

Comment: What is the "right" order?

Answer (score 2):

If you can, use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map). Maps preserve the order of the keys.

```js
let countryToCityMap = new Map([['0//America', ['New York', 'Dallas', 'SF']],
                                ['0//UK', ['London']],
                                ['1//Australia', ['Sydney', 'Melbourne']]]);

countryToCityMap.forEach((v, k) => console.log(k));
```

If you don't want your keys in the order they are inserted, you can get an array of them and [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) that however you'd like:

```
let sortedKeys = Array.from(countryToCityMap.keys()).sort((countyA, countryB)=>
{
  if(countryA is less than countryB for some reason)
  {
    return -1;
  }

  if(countryA is greater than countryB for some reason)
  {
    return 1;
  }

  //countryA and countryB are equal
  return 0;
});
```

If you don't supply a comparison function then the sort will be done by comparing the UTF-16 code points in order.